# How to make reactive array in nativescript vue?

Tags: vue.js

I know that vue doent detect change in array when we directly set an item with the index, instead, Vue.set is used, and works fine in vue.js. But i am using Vue with native script, and when I use Vue.set(myArray,index,newValue), give error. ReferenceError Vue is not defined.
Here is my script:

```js
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            comparar: function(caracter, pos) {
                                           
                //This is NOT reactive
                this.palabra_escrita[pos] = caracter

                //  This must be reactive but throws me error
                app.$set(this.palabra_escrita, pos, caracter)
                                    
                }
            
        }, //End methods        
        data() {
            return {
               
                palabra_escrita: [],                
                
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

Here is  my app.js file:

```js
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';

import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';

// Uncommment the following to see NativeScript-Vue output logs
 //Vue.config.silent = false;

new Vue({

    template: `
        <Frame>
            <HelloWorld />
        </Frame>`,

    components: {
        HelloWorld
    }
}).$start();
```

Comment: The code you provided doesn't contain neither an array nor Vue.set.

Comment: I have just added the script.

Comment: You access `app` which is not defined anywhere in sight. It should be `this.$set` instead.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot.